# Want architecture for storage and tracking of application metrics

Tags: monitoring, metrics, performance-measuring, application-monitoring

Like many modern applications I have several moving pieces as part of my current application:

- Web service
- Various queues
- Various worker processes
- etc.

To properly manage my application I want to track various arbitrary application-related metrics such as:

- Average queue length over some period of time
- Average queue processing time and/or max processing time
- Number of items processed per unit of time, or number of items of type X processed per unit of time, e.g. how many in last minute, hour, day
- and so on

I'm having trouble coming up with a logical model for this and then an actual implementation.  Some of the things I'm struggling with:

- How are these calculations made?  By the same processes that are doing the things I am measuring?  By a separate process?
- When are these calculations made?  Certainly the calculations shouldn't be synchronous with the application flow for example.
- How am I storing the results of these calculations?  Is there a database schema that lends itself to storing metrics like this?

Part of me feels like this is a solved problem and there is an architecture or pattern I should be adopting or reusing.

I ask this question purposely without mentioning the specific technologies my application is using because my gut tells me that isn't important to the pattern.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some pointers for each questions

> How are these calculations made? By the same processes that are doing
>   the things I am measuring? By a separate process?

Definitely not by the same process. The reason is, if you bind those calculations to any process that is not entirely serving this only purpose, you'll end with some scattered logic all over your services, and that will quickly become unmaintainable. Have a centralized place where all the calculation are performed. Have each piece of your achitecture sending their payload via some agnostic transfer, like REST (or something faster if you have like hundreds per second, like message queue as you mentioned).

> When are these calculations made? Certainly the calculations shouldn't
>   be synchronous with the application flow for example.

This depends on your use case. If you don't need to perform all calculations in real time, you can have a static component that receives all the incoming dataflow from your other actors, then stores them temporarily (more on that later), and another component that goes through all the newly acquired data (or all of it) to perform calculations. The latter can be scheduled by a library like Celery, or use standard cron jobs.

> How am I storing the results of these calculations? Is there a
>   database schema that lends itself to storing metrics like this?

Standard SQL could be used for that, almost any implementation of it. Now if you have metrics that are mostly time-stamped or time series data, you might take a look at [Time Series Databases (TSDB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database).

Comment: Thinking about how to get to next step. For now I'd prefer to (potentially artificially) constrain myself to relational database. One thing I'm having a heard time getting my head around is what the schema would look like. For example if I wanted to track a given metric - # of things in last min, # of things in last hour, last day, etc.Or it could be an average of some values in the same time periods. Would each of these columns in some metrics table for example? And how does the process that does the calculations "know" about these events? I'mtrying to look at the problem correctly.

Comment: Your database should have a really simple schema, probably a single table (I don't know what you want to store) that holds simple basic records about events you're interested in (e.g. client with id X queried data Y at time Z). Those tables do not know anything about 'top 10', 'average between X and Y' etc.. Instead, those specific information are retrieved by the SQL query you make (there are keywords especially made for that, e.g. `select top 50 from`). If you want to scale up, you might want to avoid making those expensive query too often, and temporarily store them in a specific table.

Comment: I see so essentially I’d have some “Events” table where I’d post one record for every event. Let’s say it’s the processing of a queue message. Columns might be queuetype, messagetype, timestamp”. And so on. So there’s no preaggregation going on, just raw events. The I’d have various queries running independently of that process to perform calculations and display them to some dashboard. That what you mean?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Emphasis on the fact that if your queries get heavier / more frequent / on more data, you might want to do these only once and keep the result in a separate table.